# Is ByteBuf.arrayOffset useless?

Tags: java, netty

I'm learning **Netty** in Action.

At the chapter **5.2.2 ByteBuf usage patterns**, there is a piece of code that confused me. It is shown below.

```
ByteBuf heapBuf = ...
if (heapBuf.hasArray()) {
    byte[] array = heapBuf.array();
    int offset = heapBuf.arrayOffset() + heapBuf.readerIndex();
    int lenght = heapBuf.readableBytes();
    handleArray(array, offset, length)
}
```

I wondered what is the use case of the `ByteBuf.arrayOffset()` method. The documentation for that method reads:

> Returns the offset of the first byte within the backing byte array of this buffer.

Then, I looked up the `arrayOffset()` method in `UnpooledHeapByteBuf.java` which implements `ByteBuf`. The implementation for the method **always** just returns `0`, as seen below.

```
@Override
public int arrayOffset() {
    return 0;
}
```

So, is `ByteBuf#arrayOffset` useless?

Comment: That's *one* class's implementation of the method.

Comment: What @user2357112 wants to say is that there may be other implementations for `ByteBuf` and it could be possible that they have a more *useful* or even *complex* implementation. So for the case of `UnpooledHeapByteBuf` returning `0` is the implementation but that does not mean that there aren't other implementations of `ByteBuf`. The method should do what the documentation states and you could imagine that other implementations indeed have a true offset that is different to `0`.

Comment: When the array offset would change? and Why to change the offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other implementations for `ByteBuf` and it could be possible that they have a more *useful* or even *complex* implementation.

So for the case of `UnpooledHeapByteBuf` returning `0` works but that does not mean that there aren't other implementations of `ByteBuf` that need a different implementation.

---

The method should do what the **documentation** states and you could imagine that other implementations indeed have an offset that is **different** to `0`. For example if they use something like a **circular-array** as backing byte array.

In that case the method needs to return the **index** of where the current **start pointer** is located at and not `0`.

Here's an example-image showing such a circular-array (the current pointer is at index `2` and not at `0`, it moves around the array while using it):

[image: circular-array example]

---

And on the **user-side**, if you want to **safely use** your `ByteBuf` object you also should use the method. You can avoid using it if you operate on `UnpooledHeapByteBuf` but even then you should not because it could be possible that they change the internal behavior with future versions.

Comment: I'm very grateful to you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

No its not useless at all as it allows us to have one huge byte array back multiple ByteBuf implementations. This in fact is done in [PooledHeapByteBuf](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/buffer/src/main/java/io/netty/buffer/PooledHeapByteBuf.java)